# When using react and flask for creating a website, why is the data not loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to follow an example that essentially displays data to the backend, as well as to the frontend; the data would be grabbed from the python flask backend.
Furthermore, I am attempting to grab data from my server.py file from the frontend using useEffect(). based on the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LNl2JlZKHA) this should work and do what I am expecting it to, but it doesn't. While I am able to get the data reference of my objects, it doesn't get displayed in the console or on the screen.
Here is my code:

```
#App.js
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/members").then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setData(data)
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {(typeof data.members === 'undefined') ? (
        <p> Loading... </p>
      ):(
        data.members.map((member, i) => (
          <p key={i}>{member}</p>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

#server.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Members API Route
@app.route('/members')
def members():
    return {"members": ["Mem1", "Mem2", "Mem3"]}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Is there a reason why this works seamlessly in the video but I can't manage to replicate the results?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the complete URL in the `fetch` method.

> `http://{HOST}:{PORT}/{PATH}`

> Like: `http://localhost:5000/members`

Comment: When I tried this it gave me the same result that I already had.

Answer (score 0):

What do your npm compiler and the console tell you?
In my case, I had to replace the

`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"`

to

`"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"`

in the package.json file.

Hope this helps.